# How to get the same node positions in d3's force layout graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I would like to create a force directed graph, but i need it to stay the same every time it is generated (with the same data).
Is there any way to do this using d3.js?

UPDATE:

I found [working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/s8pcecka/2/), which is based on using [seeded random number generator](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom)

```
// set the random seed
Math.seedrandom('mySeed');
```

Comment: you mean set the positions of the nodes ?

Comment: You can set up a force directed layout with your data in the usual way (i.e. non-deterministically), then extract the resulting positions by `console.log()`'ing them, and then save those positions into a data file that you load. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26248784/1113023) for more info and a link to an example.

Comment: @AJ_91 I need force-directed graph to set positions of my nodes, so the positions will reflect thier relations, but I need approximately the same position after another generation of graph.

Comment: @meetamit Thank you, I researched that option little bit before, but I would like to try to tame force layout first :) sorry i forgot to mention..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could by modifying D3's force layout, or by creating your own layout based on it. There are at least 3 places where randomness (Math.Random) is used in the positioning of nodes (there may be more, given the force layout references other code). You would have to eliminate all randomness in order to get the graph to display in the same way each time:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js

However, this would hamper how the layout works – it's using randomness to sort itself out into a legible diagram quickly. If your number of nodes is small, then it probably wouldn't be an issue, but a large number of nodes could just end up a tangle.

Comment: thank you Katherine, your suggestion led me to search for seeded random number generetor for javascript and replacing all random functions with this [link](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom) seems to do the job pretty well